# How to write predicate abslist(L, R)

Tags: list, prolog

Write predicate abslist(L, R) with L is a list of given numbers, R will be the list of absolute values corresponding to numbers in L.

Example:

```
?- abslist([0, -1, -2, 3], L).  
L = [0, 1, 2, 3].
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question about where you're stuck. If you're not sure where to start, have a look at the Prolog documentation (look at arithmetic expressions, for example) and you might have a look at [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) for some ideas.

Comment: I recommend to first break down the task into simpler parts. For example, start with describing the relation for a *single element*, and call it for example `integer_absolute(I, A) :- ...`. State how `I` is related to `A`. Once you have this, you can use `maplist(integer_absolute, Is, As)` to lift this relation to *lists* of integers. Ideally, the relation should be so general that you can use it in *all* directions!

Comment: `maplist(\X^Abs^(Abs #= abs(X)), Is, As)` (or `is` in place of `#=`) using `library(lambda)`.

Comment: When i add maplist(\X^Abs^(Abs #= abs(X)), Is, As). in SWI-Prolog then return result empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
absolute(X,X):-
 X>=0.

absolute(X,Y):- 
 X<0,
 Y is X * -1.

abslist([H|T],[H1|T2]):- absolute(H,H1),abslist(T,T2).

abslist([],[]).
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: Mostafa El-Messiry - Can you give me email? I have some issues that need your help. Tks :)

Comment: sure, if they are prolog related :)
mostafamesiry@gmail.com